# Clicking element fails because it incorrectly thinks it is invisible

Tags: cypress

I have several examples where I can't click on something in a popup menu.
I use code similar to below, and the assertion that this element is visible passes, but when it tries to click on that element that has been confirmed to be visible, I get the following error:

> This element is not visible because it has an effective width and height of: '0 x 0' pixels.

Here is an example of the type of tests I'm writing:

```
cy.get('.example').eq(2).find('.item-in-list').contains('Example Text').should('be.visible').click();
```

How is it possible for the `should('be.visible')` assertion to pass but for the click to fail because that same element "isn't visible"?

Comment: If waiting for the API call to finish fixes the problem, then note that `.contains('Example Text')` **does not** (bizarrely) auto-retry - and presume this content is fetched from API.

Answer (score 0):

These tests were sometimes passing and sometimes failing. Turns out that an API call would sometimes finish mid-test and cause components to re-render, thus closing my popup menu that I was trying to click. I'm still confused as to how the assertion was passing and the click was failing as often as it was (was it really re-rendering the component after my assertion passed and before the click ~50% of the time?), but confirming that that API call was completed before running my tests seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: In react apps and similar where you have no control over DOM, it tends to happen a lot, even in non-request workflows. See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695 -- best to do `.invoke('width').should('be.gt', 0).click()`